# A-Sound InvalidStateError on play() in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-audio, aframe, ar.js

Safari throws an InvalidStateError the scond time I try to play an A-Sound in an A-Frame scene:

- I try to play a sound when an AR.js marker gets visible (no event for
  that).
- I defined a new component to check if the marker's visibility
  changes and play/pause an A-Sound accordingly.
- It works fine in Chrome, but in Safari it throws an exception "InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state."

Markup:

```html
<a-sound
  id="halloween2018-sound"
  src="/sounds/halloween2018-funny.mp3" 
  autoplay="false"
  loop="true"
  soundhandler
  >
</a-sound>
```

Javascript:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('soundhandler', {       
    tick: function () {
        var soundEntity = this.el;
        if (markerGotVisible && !soundEntity.components.sound.isPlaying) {
         soundEntity.components.sound.playSound();
        }
        else if(markerGotHidden && soundEntity.components.sound.isPlaying){
         soundEntity.components.sound.pauseSound();
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Safari? Make sure you are on latest version.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos I will have users w a lot of different browser versions.

Comment: Make sure you try on latest because there were browser bugs with sound in older versions.